# Database Model for Feedback Module

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I wish to generate an online feedback system. Requirements are

- Admin can enter feedback questions
- Admin will select these questions and create a feedback session
- One Question can be used in many feedback session
- User can select any feedback session and answer/rate
- one user can answer same feedback session more than once

My table structure is

[image]

dummy data (not all columns)

```
Questions
---------
QuestionId  Question
1           Question 1
2           Question 2
3           Question 3
4           Question 4
5           Question 5


Feedback
--------
FeedbackId  Questions   
2           1,2,3,4,5                   -- Questions column has questionid from Question table

 FeedbackResults
    ---------------
    FeedbackResId   FeedbackId  QuetionID Answers    UserId
    1               2           4          4         1
    2               2           1          3         1
    3               2           5          3         1
    4               2           1          2         2
```

Please rate this design and provide valuable suggestions. Comma separated values are affordable ?

Comment: can anyone please help

Comment: User = Customer? It would help to post the DDL of these tables to make it easier to propose improvements. My first impression is that this model doesn't enable one (same) feedback session to be answered by one user more than once.

Comment: yes user is customer

Answer (score 2):

The design need to be simplified. From your explanation, it seems you only need 3 tables (Questions, Answers, and Feedback) the rest are not needed, since you can `JOIN` these tables.

> Comma separated values are affordable ?

For your design, no you don't need to, and it's not always a good idea to do it. There is some cases you can do it, and might be benefit you, but these are rare cases. Keep things simple and standard, don't join columns or rows into a single value, unless it's a requirement!

So, if your `Feedback.Questions` meant to store values of questions in comma separated value, I suggest you change that. just give each question a new feedback id, this way it'll be much more manageable.  And instead of storing the question string, just store the questionId (FK) instead. this way it'll be more appropriate and would process faster.

So I suggest you remodel it to :

```
#ListStatus
- Id [PK|IDENTITY]
- Description

#ListRate 
- Id [PK|IDENTITY]
- Description

#FeedbackQuestions 
- Id [PK|IDENTITY]
- Question 
- CreatedAt
- UpdatedAt 
- Deleted
- StatusId
- UserId

#FeedbackAnswers 
- Id [PK|IDENTITY]
- QuestionId 
- Answer 
- CreatedAt 
- UpdatedAt 
- Deleted
- UserId 

#Feedback 
- Id [PK|IDENTITY]
- RateId
- QuestionId
- AnswerId 
- CreatedAt 
- Deleted
- UserId
```

The `Listxxx` tables would store a list of fixed descriptive values. For instance, `ListRate` would store the rate options such as Excellent, Very Good, Good, Fair, Poor ..etc. When a user rates an answer, the Id of `ListRate` would be inserted into `Feedback` table.

Also, since we defined them with a prefix `List` it would be standardized in the system design, for general use purpose on other tables, and best yet, easier to understand (so developers would know the purpose of these tables just from the table name).

I got confused between `UserId` & `CustomerId`, but I used `userId` so you're working with `logged-in users` doesn't matter if is it from `Admin` or some customer using the system, at the end, you need to record the `Username` that made this changes .

Another thing you might need is to add a category for the questions, and maybe the Feedback as well. This will be very helpful in filtering the results. You don't want to depend on any column that store user input with open text, it'll be a real pain in the neck. So, adding a category to the questions, which will store it's values in another table to have two columns (one for displaying text for user, the other one is the id) will make things easier to work with, and if you see that you can add more filtering options (either supporting sub-category or tags ..etc) go for it.

Sample  :

**Questions Table**

```
| Id |   Question |            CreatedAt | UpdatedAt | Deleted | StatusId | UserId |
|----|------------|----------------------|-----------|---------|----------|--------|
|  1 | Question 1 | 2019-12-14T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) |        1 | User 1 |
|  2 | Question 2 | 2019-12-14T20:40:15Z |    (null) |  (null) |        2 | User 2 |
|  3 | Question 3 | 2019-12-14T07:05:01Z |    (null) |  (null) |        3 | User 3 |
```

**Answers Table**

```
| Id | QuestionId |   Answer |            CreatedAt | UpdatedAt | Deleted |  UserId |
|----|------------|----------|----------------------|-----------|---------|---------|
|  1 |          1 | Answer 1 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 50 |
|  2 |          1 | Answer 2 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 50 |
|  3 |          1 | Answer 3 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 70 |
|  4 |          2 | Answer 1 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 70 |
```

**Feedback Table**

```
| Id | RateId | QuestionId | AnswerId |            CreatedAt | UpdatedAt | Deleted |  UserId |
|----|--------|------------|----------|----------------------|-----------|---------|---------|
|  1 |      1 |          1 |        3 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) |   Admin |
|  2 |      2 |          2 |        4 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 23 |
|  3 |      2 |          1 |        2 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) |  User 5 |
|  4 |      5 |          1 |        3 | 2019-07-05T00:00:00Z |    (null) |  (null) | User 23 |
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab421/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am not still clear with your design. which table has feedback sessions (refer my point 2: Admin will select these questions and create a feedback session). There can be multiple feedback sessions from which a user/customer can select the feedback to answer

Comment: @SachuMine Feedback table(the last one) should stores the feedback sessions.

Comment: could you please put some sample data in tables. The id of Feedback table is unique? How we we know which feedbak session is answered?

Comment: @SachuMine I have added a sample data and a live demo so you'll have a better view on the model.